# npm run scripts does not working

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-run

I have just initialized a new project with Node.js and trying making the scripts in package.json file to be working.

For example I have the next package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description server",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Something LTD",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "docusaurus-init": "^1.0.2",
    "exceljs": "^1.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-limiter": "^1.6.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongojs": "^2.6.0",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "point-in-polygon": "^1.0.1",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "t4u": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Then I either trying run `npm test` or `npm start` or `npm run start` 
but all of them just doing nothing and returns nothing in console. Even the test script just not printing anything.

I have tried to do:

```
npm config set --ignore-scripts false
```

However that did not work.

Comment: Can you check your version of node:
`node -v`
And check version of npm
`npm -v`

Comment: @user2590928 My version of node is: v9.2.0 and npm version 6.1.0

Comment: Can you post the code in app.js - It may be possible that the code is running but your app is not coded to do anything - This could explain why you see no errors

Comment: I have just commented all of the code and wrote just some console.log which get displayed on terminal when doing node app.js but not on npm start

Comment: What happens if you run `npm run test`?

Comment: Nothing. BTW when I am changing the "name" to something that includes spaces, like this: app name (notice the space) I receive the next error: Invalid name: "taxi4you server"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/razbuchnik/.npm/_logs/2018-07-13T04_17_10_092Z-debug.log
razs-MacBook:server razbuchnik$

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```bsh
npm config set ignore-scripts false
```

Was solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

`npm run-script start` worked for me (`npm run` is an alias to `npm run-script` as stated in [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) but not sure why alias didnt work)

hope this helps people who are still facing the issue after setting `ignore-script` as false

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can also edit directly a file on the following location

`C:\Users\[Your username]\.npmrc`

and set `ignore-scripts=false`